# How to not create a big if list in this part of my code?

Tags: php

I don't want to create a big if list for all the story chapters of my website.

if $commentformname[$a] is equal to the number of the current chapter, then I make an array $commentonchapter1[$a] saying that a comment was inserted in the chapter 1, and chapter 2, and so on.

So if a comment was posted in the chapter 2, a array called commentonchapter2 will be created.

```
if ($sitecomments == true) {
    $c = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $z = 0;
    #defines the comment form name, name of who commented, the comment text and time (to be converted, example: 2020-04-09T15:53:07.580Za > 12:53 09/04/2020)
    while ($c <= $commentsnumb) {
        $commentformname[$z] = $comments[$i];
        $i++;

        $commenttername[$z] = $comments[$i];
        $i++;

        $commenttext[$z] = $comments[$i];
        $i++;

        $commenttime[$z] = $comments[$i];
        $i++;

        $c++;
        $z++;
    }

    #shows the text of the comments tab
    echo '<hr class="'.$sitehr2.'" />'."\n";
    echo $divzoomanim.'<'.$n.'><p></p><br /><b>'.$tabnames[7].': '.$orangespan.$commentsnormalnumb.$spanc.' '.$icons[12].'</b><br /><br /><p></p></'.$n.'>'.$divc.'<hr class="'.$sitehr.'" />'."\n";

    $i = 0;
    $z = 0;
    #converts the comment date and time
    #example
    #from 2020-04-09T15:53:07.580Za
    #to 12:53 09/04/2020
    while ($z <= $commentsnumb) {
        $commenttime[$z] = substr($commenttime[$z], 0, -1);
        $commenttime[$z] = date("H:i d/m/Y", strtotime($commenttime[$z]));

        $z++;
    }

    $a = 0;
    $z = 0;
    $i = 0;
    #styles the form name
    #example
    #from "pequenata-comment-7"
    #to '<b>Commented on form "Pequenata-comment-7"</b>'
    while ($a <= $commentsnumb) {
        if ($lang == $langs[0] or $lang == $langs[1]) {
            $commentformname[$i] = '<b>'.$commenttxt3.' '.$commenttxt5.' '.strtolower($formtxt).':</b> "'.ucwords($commentformname[$i]).'"';
        }

        if ($lang == $langs[2]) {
            $commentformname[$i] = '<b>'.$commenttxt3.' '.$commenttxt4.' '.strtolower($formtxt).':</b> "'.ucwords($commentformname[$i]).'"';
        }

        $a++;
        $z++;
        $i++;
    }

    $a = 0;
    $a2 = 1;
    $i = 0;
    $z = 0;
    $c = 0;
    $v = 0;
    $b = 0;
    $commentschapternumb = 0;
    #Generates the array of the website comments
    while ($c <= $commentsnumb) {
        #Generates the comments of the website if the strlen of $commentformname[$a] is equal to 45, String: <b>Commented on form "Pequenata-comment-7"</b>
        if (strlen($commentformname[$a]) == 45) {
            $cmntsgeral[$b] = '<'.$m.' class="'.$textstyle2.'" style="text-align:left;border-width:3px;border-color:'.$bordercolor.';border-style:solid;"><div style="margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;">'.'<br /><b>'.$a2.' - '.$commenttername[$i].'</b> - '.$commenttime[$i].'<br />'.$commentformname[$i].' '.'<hr class="'.$sitehr3.'" />'.$commenttext[$i].'<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />'.$divc.'</'.$m.'>'."<br />"."\n";
            #Dispalyer disabled because of showing the wrong array (using $z, so it was tring to print a number on the array that didn't existed ($cmntschapter was incrementing on $z)
            #echo $cmntsgeral[$z];

            $a2++;
            $b++;
        }

        #Generates the array of the chapter comments
        if (strlen($commentformname[$a]) == 47) {
            $cmntschapter[$v] = '<'.$m.' class="'.$textstyle2.'" style="text-align:left;border-width:3px;border-color:'.$bordercolor.';border-style:solid;"><div style="margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;">'.'<br /><b>'.$a2.' - '.$commenttername[$i].'</b> - '.$commenttime[$i].'<br />'.$commentformname[$i].' '.'<hr class="'.$sitehr3.'" />'.$commenttext[$i].'<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />'.$divc.'</'.$m.'>'."<br />"."\n";
            #Doesn't show the chapter comments because they shouldn't be showed in the website comments tab
            #echo $cmntschapter[$z];
            $v++;
            $commentschapternumb++;
        }

        $a++;
        $i++;
        $z++;
        $c++;
    }

    #Shows the website comments on the comments tab of the site
    $z = 0;
    while ($z <= $commentsnormalnumbtowrite) {
        echo $cmntsgeral[$z];

        $z++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Run the array through a foreach or for loop and get the key/value pairs. `a array called commentonchapter2 will be created.` Do you mean an array *entry* will be created?

Comment: _Do you mean an array entry will be created?_
.
No, if there is two comments on the array $commentonchapter1, that means that there's two comments on the chapter 1, that needs to be an array, so I can show the two comments on the chapter page

Comment: You really should save this info in one array, it would be much easier to handle that way. Key would be chapter name, value would be a nested array with entered comments. Then you could iterate over the parent and see if there are values set, if so, get the key value, then display the content of the nested array. Using all these iterators to handle different arrays is quite confusing and will be a pain in the long run!

Comment: @dalelandry and how do I do that?, I don't know how to do a nested array, and I'm not sure if I understood your explanation

Comment: Update your question and add the code you use to create your arrays now

Comment: Edited the comment.